# Log4j How disable only FATAL entries

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, switch-statement

Do you know how to disable only FATAL logs outputs in configuration for Log4j?

All other entries like TRACE, WARN, DEBUG, INFO, ERROR we would still like to have.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: We have one giant application and logging is everywhere.
We have to disable Fatal logs because we do not monitor them anymore.
The way the application is written is that it produces unnecesary fatal logs.
We try to avoid to change application because it is already in production and costs for changing is to expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal mechanisms of setting a logger level or a *threshold* on an appender only allow you to disable messages *below* a certain level while including all higher level messages. In your case you want to suppress messages at the highest priority level but include lower ones, so you'll have to use a [LevelRangeFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/LevelRangeFilter.html).

Filters cannot be configured in `log4j.properties` so if that's what you're currently using you'll have to switch to XML or programmatic configuration instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to change it in configuration file like Kunal Surana wrote above with example like: "log4j.logger.com.abc=TRACE,WARN,DEBUG,INFO,ERROR"?

Comment: @MerkoSMS you can't configure filters in the `.properties` configuration format, so the easiest approach is to replace your log4j.properties with the equivalent log4j.xml and put the filter definition in there.

Comment: @MerkoSMS there's a strong assumption built in to Log4J in many places that anywhere you care about messages of a particular level you also want to see "more important" messages as well.  The only way to see messages at one level (e.g. ERROR) without also seeing more important messages (e.g. FATAL) is to use a filter.

Answer (score -1):

Set the level of package you want to enable logs.
Example, package is com.abc, then set the level as

```
    log4j.logger.com.abc=TRACE,WARN,DEBUG,INFO,ERROR
```

Comment: That would set the _level_ of the logger to TRACE (i.e. log everything) and send its output to appenders named WARN, DEBUG, INFO and ERROR - the syntax is exactly one level followed by zero or more appender names.

Comment: OK thanks. 
Yes, FATAL level is the lowest. The only way to disable FATAL is to set the level to OFF using  `log.setLevel(Level.OFF)`. But this will disable all the logs